# 16.10 keeps resetting settings for wallpaper, keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, desktop-background, reset

Since upgrading to 16.10 from 16.04, I'm seeing that a number of ubuntu preferences keep getting reset at regular intervals.

For instance, I'm using variety to shuffle my desktop wallpaper, but every half hour or so something else seems to reset it to this default orange ubuntu-supplied wallpaper.

Similarly, I've been changing the keyboard shortcuts for window placement in CCSM, but they seem to get reset during my session, and have to be re-set whenever I reboot or re-login.

Anyone have any idea what's causing this annoying behaviour?